# IDE for yeoman framework

Tags: angularjs, ide, javascript-framework, yeoman, yeoman-generator

I need to do an angularjs project using yeomen framework.

I have tried to open the yeomen generated project in Netbeans. But Netbeans is not detecting the project and not able to open it.

Can anyone say the best open source IDE for this?

Comment: Tried out webstorm 7.0.2 ?

Comment: in webstorm just open the directory

Comment: webstorm ++, its great

Comment: Why the hell is this question closed as off-topic? It's a pertinent question and I want to see answers.